# Sample Size Calculation of Pilot Study

Tags: sample-size

I want to calculate the sample size for my pilot study. My subjects will undergo a certain test once taking a substance before the test, once taking a placebo. My goal is to find out if the substance effects up to two parameters during the test (not sure yet if I can measure both). Am I right, that a paired t-test will help me later in comparing my results? I was thinking of a two-tailed test since my parameters could go up or down. I would like to set the confidence to 95% and the power to 80%. 
I tried looking for various online tools to help me calculate this but I haven't found the right one yet. Does anybody know a good website or can provide me with an equation?

Answer (score 0):

You should check this site: http://www.statmethods.net/stats/power.html

Following may work for you:

```
pwr.t.test(n = , d = 0.5, sig.level = 0.05, power = 80 , type = "paired")
```